# Don't know the Ubuntu's password! How to uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

I got my laptop with Ubuntu however, I have no idea about the password that was set on it. How may I uninstall it?

Comment: Just install windows... or any OS. Really, most OS doesn't care of what it's installed.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is an Operating System.
You can not uninstall it like a normal program.
You should install another OS in it.
While you are installing new OS, you will be able to delete the partition where Ubuntu OS installed.

Answer (score 0):

Previous question has the solution for your answer, although I can tell you to change the password installed. Hope it would work without any problem. Follow these steps:

1. Open terminal(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute:

   ```
   su
   ```

   It will login to **root** without asking to any password. I'm sure that you **root** user password would not be set if you got a newly installed Ubuntu.
2. Now execute following command to re-set your Ubuntu's user password:

   ```
   passwd <username>
   ```

   eg: `passwd saurav` if saurav is the user to which you want to change the password. It will ask to type and re-type a new UNIX password. Just set your new password and exit from root.
3. For example I'm pasting the output of my terminal:

   ```
   saurav@saurav-P4I45Gx-PE:~$ su
   saurav-P4I45Gx-PE# passwd saurav
   Enter new UNIX password: 
   Retype new UNIX password: 
   passwd: password updated successfully
   saurav-P4I45Gx-PE# exit
   saurav@saurav-P4I45Gx-PE:~$
   ```

I would suggest you to use Ubuntu, and don't remove it. Hope you too like it.. :) 
Reply if something goes wrong.